# [C#]Get Sourcecode of Website (404 ERROR)

Tags: c#, web, httpwebrequest

i have to get the sourcecode of ~1000 Websites for a School Project. I use the HTTP Webrequest in a for loop. But more than the half websites on my list returns the 404 Error so the Website cannot be found. When i surf to this website in Chrome, Firefox or Internet Explorer everything works fine.

Heres my Code to get the Sourcecode:

```
public string getSource(string url){
        string urlAddress = url;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;

            if (response.CharacterSet == null)
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            }
            else
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
            }

            data = readStream.ReadToEnd();

            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Maybe it doesn't works because of the Mass of 1000 Websites?

Comment: Perhaps you should give us some of the successful and some of the failed urls to check out.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to set the user agent to a known browser for a lot of sites as they will reject requests from unknown "browsers". Try this before you call request.GetResponse

```
var agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 9.0; en-US)";
request.Headers.Add("user-agent", agent);
```

Comment: Hm when i use this code my program runs only through the lines of the file without downloading the sourcecode.